# Add Special Character Option in jquery Te Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor

All options I found in jqueryte text editor which I need but unable to find option for adding special characters. I check all the documentation of jqueryte but I didn't find it. Is there any way to add it or not. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my all effort but I didn't find special character option in jqueryte text editor but I found tinymce editor which has all the tools (special character also). You can use it instead of jqueryte.